# Object button don't call method in python

Tags: python, odoo

i'm trying to call a function in python with following buttons:

```
<form string="Settings" class="oe_form_configuration">
     <header>
         <button string="Apply" type="object" name="execute" class="oe_highlight"/>
         <button string="Cancel" type="object" name="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
    </header>
     ...
</form>
```

But, they will never be called. After some time, I saw that is just called the method of update, that is, def write(...).

Can someone help me understand the problem?

EDIT:
Actually, I remove all logic from methods:

```
def execute(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    pass

def cancel(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    pass
```

Best regards

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: If you could provide the function prototypes, would be useful

Comment: Hi all, I edited my code with code

Comment: Don't you just add the parentheses to the method call? `name="execute()"`

Comment: @ATLUS not, it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using old v7 API, try v8:

```
@api.one
def execute(self):
    pass

@api.one
def cancel(self):
    pass
```

(or *multi* instead of *one*. [Here's the difference](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decorator.html))

Comment: Of course, for mistake I put wrong version. I will edit inline. Can you see again please?

Comment: 1-control that the model of the view is the same of the model of the class containing the two methods. 2-which version of odoo are you using?

Comment: Hi, yes, the model is the same. I'm using v9